# Satisfaction of constraint 'C<T>' depends on itself

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-concepts

I have a program that worked well in Visual Studio (probably because some code branches are never executed), but GCC and Clang reject to compile it.

After simplification, I got the following reduced example:

```
struct A {
    void f( const int & ) {}
    template <typename T, typename = decltype( g( std::declval<const T&>(), std::declval<A&>() ) )>
    void f( const T& t ) {
        g( t, *this );
    }
};

template <typename T>
concept C = requires ( const T& t, A & a ) {
    { a.f( t ) };
};

template <C T>
void g( const T& t, A & a ) {
    a.f( t );
}

int main() {
    A a;
    g( 1.f, a );
}
```

Here struct `A` has two overloaded methods `f`. One takes `const int &` on input, and the other - function template - checks the availability of global function `g` with appropriate arguments using SFINAE.

Global function template `g` from its side checks with concept `C<T>` that it can delegate the work to `f` method (I guess not template one as was conceived originally).

Then the program calls `f` method with a `float` argument. Both Clang and GCC complain:

```
error: satisfaction of atomic constraint 'requires(const T& t, A& a) {{a->A::f(t)};} [with T = T]' depends on itself
```

but MSVC accepts it. Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/o56he1zW5

As can be seen from the assembly, MSVC produces the call to `g<float>(float const &,A &)`, which in turn calls `A::f<float,void>(float const &)` and vice versa. And running the program stops with stack overflow due to infinite recursion (гnfortunately, Godbolt-service cannot run MSVC code.) And `A::f( const int & )` is never called at all, but if one eliminates or deletes it, then compilation in MSVC also fails with the errors:

```
error C2672: 'g': no matching overloaded function found
note: could be 'void g(const T &,A &)'
note: the associated constraints are not satisfied
note: the concept 'C<float>' evaluated to false
note: the expression is invalid
```

Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/WMW7v4eoK

Is it a MSVC bug or the program is ill formed and no diagnostics required in this case?

Comment: I have no clue about the language-lawyering part but I managed to get it compiling by modifying the concept slightly and removed the SFINAE part from `f` - but then I got an infinite recursion, because `g` calls `a.f` that calls `g` ... etc. I'm not sure what the terminating condition was in MSVC where this worked.

Comment: Is there any reason why you use concepts in one place and SFINAE in another? `A::f` could have a constraint instead of using some `decltype` tricks.

Comment: @JanSchultke, the original code was written not by myself, I just reduced it to minimal example and put it here. I agree that using concepts in both places would be clearer.

Comment: @Fedor Is it possible to see how MSVC instantiates it? I found it hard to figure out what they use to terminate the perceived recursion. Too bad https://cppinsights.io/ doesn't have a MSVC mode :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo, it looks like I oversimplified the code before putting it here. It turns out that MSVC produced `A::f<float,void>(float const &)` that calls `g<float>(float const &,A &)` and vice versa. It can be seen in assembly following the link in the question. And running it fails with stack overflow due to infinite recursion. Unfortunately,  godbolt cannot run MSVC code so I missed it. And `A::f( const int & )` is never called, but if one deletes it MSVC returns an error: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/WMW7v4eoK